# Footline formatting - spacing and color of the shortitle

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color

I am having trouble with the footline - I couldn't find the answer.

1. How can I make the space between my name and affiliation (bottom left)?
2. How do I change the color of "Introduction and Overview" (middle) to be the same color as the rest of the text in the footline?

[image]

I have this code for my footline:

```
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor(\insertshortinstitute)
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\input{tcilatex}
\begin{document}

\title[Introduction and Overview]{Econ 196, Financial Crises - Morals and
Markets}
\author[Eric Fischer]{Eric Fischer}
\institute[UCSC]{}
\date{March 31, 2015}
\maketitle
```

Comment: For 1, use `\insertshortauthor~(\insertshortinstitute)` (note (`~`) and for 2, use `...center]{author in head/foot}%` for all three `beamercolorbox`es instead of title and date.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

1. As already mentioned in [Footline formatting - spacing and color of the shortitle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236270/footline-formatting-spacing-and-color-of-the-shortitle#comment559970_236270) you can insert a space with `~`
2. To set the colour of the title: `\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg}`

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~(\insertshortinstitute)
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg}

\begin{document}

\title[Introduction and Overview]{Econ 196, Financial Crises - Morals and
Markets}
\author[Eric Fischer]{Eric Fischer}
\institute[UCSC]{}
\date{March 31, 2015}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]